# What actually constitutes a diatonic scale?

Tags: scales

Trying to do my own homework here! I've read that only the standard major scale is diatonic. Also, I've read that the harmonic and melodic minor scales are also diatonic. Also I've read that the notes from any scale can be called diatonic to that scale. I've always gone with the first two definitions, but I've been wrong before! With such conflicting views, is there a definitive definition?

Comment: Don't the answers to [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/35767/9724) answer your question?

Comment: @MattL. - they would have done, but I have read several conflicting definitions, so now, I'm asking the question to further enlighten myself and others. It is certainly *an* answer to the question.

Comment: _With such conflicting views, is there a definitive definition?_ Perhaps your question provides its own answer: No, there is no definitive definition. Who would you expect to define it and make it "the law of the land"? Beethoven?  Stravinsky?  Thelonious Monk? Phillip Glass? It's clearly one of those fuzzy terms - everyone uses it and no one knows **exactly** what it means, but from the context its meaning is  (hopefully) understood. _the notes from any scale can be called diatonic to that scale_ - that's how I use it lately. Sometimes I am corrected, but now I stopped worrying about that...

Answer (score 2):

https://www.britannica.com/art/diatonic

> Diatonic, in music, any stepwise arrangement of the seven “natural” pitches (scale degrees) forming an octave without altering the established pattern of a key or mode—**in particular**, the major and natural minor scales.

I emphasized the **in particular** to show that it doesn't necessarily apply to just the major and natural minor scales.

The way I understood it, diatonic described a note's relationship to a scale/chord. In other words, C# is not a diatonic note in the G major scale, but D is; F# is diatonic in the C Lydian mode, but G# is not.

Comment: _I emphasized the in particular..._ - +1 for that. _The way I understood it, diatonic described..._ - that doesn't seem to be what it says in the definition you cited but no matter - we certainly use it that way. I also often wonder how authoritative a generic resource like Britannica can be when it comes to something so specialized and idiosyncratic as musical terminology.

Answer (score 1):

A common definition for the *Diatonic Scale* is that of the *Major Scale* or the *Natural Minor Scale*. However, the word *diatonic* is often used generically and is not as strictly defined as, say, the *Major Scale*.

So, for instance, many will refer to any mode of the Major Scale as being diatonic. You will also see many theorists referring to the various triads (and other chords) built from the Major Scale as being diatonic.

So, in short, the term *Major Scale* is more specific and strictly defined than the more generic word *Diatonic* (although the term *Diatonic Scale* almost always means, or implies, the *Major Scale*).

more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatonic_and_chromatic#Modern_meanings

Comment: _The most common definition of the Diatonic Scale is that of the Major Scale_  - is that the most common **usage**?  I hardly think so. How did you arrive at this conclusion - you checked a lot of dictionaries? Any other sources besides wikipedia - perhaps some authoritative scholars? The OP, who is quite knowledgeable, has already mentioned reading differently in various sources - what is it about this answer makes it more correct than the other definitions the OP has mentioned?

Comment: Fair enough, I can't say that I counted every possible resource. However, doing simple search of *"Diatonic Scale"* in google and reading through the first 5 entries (1 of which was the Encyclopædia Britannica) showed that they all defined a diatonic scale as consisting of the notes of the Major scale (or Natural Minor scale). And that was the point I was attempting to make. I'll edit the opening sentence of my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

The definitive definition would probably be based on the scale the name implies, and its historical origin, from the Ancient Greek and probably pythagorean diatonic scale.

The confusion may come from the colloquial use of the term, which includes using Major scale as a base, or includes scale modifications such as Harmonic Minor.

From what I remember, my college theory class defined the diatonic scale as specifically comprised of a pattern of whole tones and semitones, with the semitones fully separated.

The Harmonic Minor scale used in a melodic context (playing the augmented second jump from the minor 6th to the major 7th in the melodic line) would not be considered true diatonic, but a modified scale. Used Harmonically where the raised 7th degree of the scale is used in context and as part of a Dominant chord and not used as a leading tone to the tonic, then the Harmonic scale could be described as diatonic.

To quote Grove's Dictionary of Music:  "Diatonic (from Gk. dia tonos : ‘proceeding by whole tones’ ) Based on or derivable from an octave of seven notes in a particular configuration, as opposed to Chromatic and other forms of Scale . A seven-note scale is said to be diatonic when its octave span is filled by five tones and two semitones, with the semitones maximally separated, for example the major scale (T–T–S–T–T–T–S). The natural minor scale and the church modes ( see Mode ) are also diatonic."

So, specifically five tones and two semitones. At least, that's how I learned it.

Comment: Which then makes the Lydian mode a perfect candidate, with the same premise being fulfilled - T-T-T-S-T-T-S.